# KVM tag, synonyms on the same area of expertise...

Tags: discussion, tags

So, we kave KVM, the Kernel-based Virtual Machine and KVM, the Keyboard Video Mouse switch. Both are correct and both are heavily used on the sysadmin world. Luckily enough we have only a [few questions on the tag](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/kvm) but what to do with the Tag Wiki? I have some alternatives:

- Add both definitions to the tag wiki
- Create a KVM-Switch tag and leav KVM for the virtualisation tool

What do you think.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My vote is to go with [kvm-switch](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/kvm-switch) for such things and [kvm](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/kvm) for the virtualization technology. If we wanted to get fancy with it, we could create [kvm](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/kvm) as a synonym for [kvm-virtualization](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/kvm-virtualization).

Comment: +1 except I really don't like the [tag:kvm-virtualization] idea... how about [linux-kvm] or some/anything else?

Comment: @ChrisS KVM being a rather specific Linux technology, [linux-kvm] makes lots of sense.

Comment: KVM is already ported to FreeBSD so it's not that specific.

Comment: Anyway, retagged the only KVM switch question to [tag:kvm-switch] and left the [tag:kvm] alone with virtualisation things.

Comment: @coredump, it's called KQemu on FreeBSD though; it should probably be a synonym or something Linux-KVM and FreeBSD-KQemu