# Tag reorganisation kvm*

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging

[This is related](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1404/kvm-tag-synonyms-on-the-same-area-of-expertise) but it doesn't look like it was fully resolved.

Tag [kvm](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/kvm) has (at least) two potential uses. Some work was done as per the link above to split it into [kvm](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/kvm) and [kvm-switch](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/kvm-switch). However, as the status of [kvm](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/kvm) was left unresolved some questions that should have been [kvm-switch](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/kvm-switch) were tagged [kvm](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/kvm), this has been fixed.

The tags we need to resolve are [kvm](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/kvm), [linux-kvm](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/linux-kvm), [libvirt-kvm](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/libvirt-kvm) and  [kvm-switch](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/kvm-switch).

*It appears that the KVM technology has been ported to Iluminos, OpenIndiana and related technologies which makes using [kvm-virtualization](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/kvm-virtualization) more appropriate than [linux-kvm](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/linux-kvm) so*

Proposal

- [kvm-switch](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/kvm-switch) 33 questions - leave as is.
- [ip-kmvm](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/ip-kmvm) (13 questions) - leave as is.

Create [kvm-virtualization](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/kvm-virtualization)

- [linux-kvm](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/linux-kvm) 61 questions - remove and replace with [kvm-virtualization](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/kvm-virtualization).
- [libvirt-kvm](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/libvirt-kvm) (26 questions) remove and where applicable replace with [kvm-virtualization](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/kvm-virtualization)
- [kvm](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/kvm) (363 questions) remove where applicable replace with [kvm-virtualization](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/kvm-virtualization) and blackhole.

Given the size of the job I imagine we'll need to get an SE dev involved in dealing with [kvm](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/kvm) at least.

Your thoughts please.

Comment: [tag:linux-kvm] and [tag:kvm-switch], yes please! [tag:ipkvm] is rather lonely, too.

Comment: Is [tag:ip-kvm] a synonym of [tag:kvm-switch] or does it stand alone (which was my thinking) ?

Comment: I would consider ip-kvm and kvm-switch to be separate beasts (at least until in-rack push-button KVM switches finally die off)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless anyone objects I will be writing to the team and asking them to implement the changes above on Friday 10th Feb 2012.

Comment: Seems sensible to me (as does [this proposed change to the reorganized FAQ](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/2871/32986))